# Join Two Tables and then Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have two tables in a MySql database:

```
COUNTRY
---------------
id, 
country_name
```

and

```
CITY 
---------------
c_id, 
city_name, 
id
```

The Country is a parent table of city: `country.id` = `city.id`

I want to display the following:

```
Country_name   count of cities 
------------------------------
USA            333  
UAE            293  
....
```

*Show all either if country is null or city is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    cn.country_name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.c_id) AS count_of_cities
FROM
    COUNTRY cn LEFT JOIN
    CITY c ON c.id = cn.id
GROUP BY cn.country_name
```